# Check WCF service is working or not by output typing URL

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-endpoint, web-config

I have created a WCF service in ASP.net. I want to check the service is working or not before moving forward.
So can sombody suggests what is the exact URL to type and see the output. 
Find my web.config file.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService11" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
        contract="Myservice.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService1">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WcfServiceLibrary1/Service1/"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService11"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService11">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Since your service is using `wsHttpBinding`, it's a **SOAP** web service, and you cannot just "test" a SOAP service in your browser. You need to use e.g. the WCF Test Client or a tool like `SoapUI` to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [wcftestclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.90).aspx) to test service

you can set the wcf project as startup project and debug the solution, it will start in wcftestclient and automatically add your service.

or  open directly from "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe" - VS2010

from here you can invoke the serviceby passing parameters(if any) and test.

[here is another link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wcftoolsteamblog/archive/2010/01/04/tips-for-launching-wcf-test-client.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean check at the client side,then you can catch the Exception like below and do what you want to do

- CommunicationObjectFaultedException      //Communication is wrong
- EndpointNotFoundException                //EndPoint is not found or working
- FaultException                           //FaultException thrown by the server